# How to work with update.one() when UpdateWriteResult seems to be deprecated

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am working on a ReactiveMongo upgrade(0.20.X to 1.0.7) and have noticed that when calling `update.one()` I get a complex return value of `Future[(GenericCollection[collection.Pack] with CollectionMetaCommands)#UpdateWriteResult]`

```
import reactiveMongo.api._
import reactivemongo.api.bson._
import reactivemongo.api.bson.collection.BSONCollection

def updateAsFuture(collection: BSONCollection, selector: BSONDocument, modifier: BSONDocument, upsert: Boolean = false, multi: Boolean = false) = {
    collection.update.one(selector, modifier, upsert=upsert, multi=multi).map(f => f)
  }
```

The `insert.one()` and `delete.one()` seem to be working fine, returning `Future[WriteResult]` matching what the documentation explains.

I am trying to make sense of all these discrepancies. A detailed example of the typing with `update.one` would be much appreciated

Comment: You should never ever return a `UpdateWriteResult` or a `WriteResult`. It internal dependent types. Either return the number of updated, or the updated document.

Comment: Alright, I get what you are getting at.